# sendmail does not perform masquerade

Tags: sendmail

I hoped that following the reply in question: Sendmail configure masquerade domain, would help me too, but it (still) does not.

On the server account: test exists.
The server (amongst others) is called: mail.server in (/etc/hosts)

I try to make sendmail change: **test@mail.server** to: **test@domain.org**.

Up till now I've been unsuccessful.

sendmail.mc contains:

```
MASQUERADE_AS(`domain.org')dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(domain.org)dnl
```

even so.
E-mail sent from roundcube by LOCAL OS user: test, **always** comes from: `"Roodbms:Test" <test@mail.server>`.

Off course **I want/need this to be**: `"Roodbms:Test" <test@domain.org>`.

**Is there no way to make sendmail do this?**

Extra info:

```
sendmail -bv test@domain.org
test@domain.org... deliverable: mailer esmtp, host domain.org., user test@domain.org
sendmail -bv otheruser@domain.org
otheruser@domain.org... deliverable: mailer esmtp, host domain.org., user otheruser@domain.org

sendmail -bv test
root... deliverable: mailer local, user root
sendmail -bv otheruser
otheruser... deliverable: mailer local, user otheruser
```

**Why the difference for both the local accounts?**

Answer (score 0):

So... you are trying to masquerade the `domain.org` as `domain.org`.
Then you are trying to test the delivery.
Then you are testing local unqualified user.

From what I see - everything works as intended.

May be you should masquerade the `mail.server` domain instead ?
And the answer to the second question lies in an answer to a question "Do you have `local-host-names` configured ?".

Anyway, the entire post and your configuration assumptions that can be made from your results mean that you probably have no idea about what you are really doing.

Comment: If the info in the question on this forum with title: "Sendmail configure masquerade domain", would have been correct my first question would not have been necessary. Your deduction that I'm not familiar with sendmail is correct. The information to be found about sendmail in most cases is very brief and lacks the aspect: **why**. The **how** is covered in many cases, but the **why** is left out. This does little to get a better grasp of the topic.